# I am trying to create a Connection Pool with single connection using PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager and ClosableHttpClient for HTTPS and reuse it

Tags: ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x

Trying to create a connection pool, where only single HTTPS connection will be created and when subsequent request comes previous connection pool would be used. Currently when I am trying to hit any request each time new connection is getting Established and previous connection is going into time wait state.

Below code-snippet I am using, it's working for HTTP connection but not for HTTPS

```
  SslConfigurator sslConfig = SslConfigurator.newInstance().keyStoreFile(this.connectionInfo.getKeyStorePath()).keyStorePassword(connectionInfo.getKeyStorePassword()).keyStoreType("JKS").trustStoreFile(this.connectionInfo.getKeyStorePath()).trustStorePassword(connectionInfo.getKeyStorePassword()).securityProtocol("TLS");
                logger.info("SSL CONFIG Accepted");
                sslContext = sslConfig.createSSLContext();
                SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext,NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);
                logger.info("SSL CONTEXT CREATED, Building Client" );

                Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory> create().register("https", sslsf).build();
                connManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(socketFactoryRegistry);
                connManager.setMaxTotal(1);
                connManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(1);

                config = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(60000).setConnectionRequestTimeout(60000).setSocketTimeout(60000).build();
                client = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultRequestConfig(config).setConnectionManager(connManager).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

> connManager.setMaxTotal(1);

I am not sure why you think this has no effect because this should definitely restrict the total number of connections in the pool to just one at a time.

In your particular case however you should be using `BasicHttpClientConnectionManager` instead of `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager`